# Steps to take when rebasing a branch thats branched off a branch which is branched off a main branch

Tags: git

I keep getting nightmare rebases and I think it's because I'm taking the wrong steps.

I've got 3 branches ... mainbranch, branch1, branch2 ... branch1 is a branch off mainbranch ... branch2 is a branch off branch1

- branch1 is 1 commit ahead of mainbranch
- branch2 is 1 commit ahead of branch1

So it's in this state that I have problems when I ... `git fetch -p`; `git pull -r` ... on mainbranch. I now want to bring the new changes on mainbranch into branch1 and branch2. This is what I am currently doing:

```
git checkout mainbranch
git fetch -p
git pull -r
git checkout branch1
git rebase -i mainbranch (i dont squash commits or anything like that)
git checkout branch2
git rebase -i branch1 <<< this causes the problem
```

When I run that last command I have a nightmare with conflicts. I am assuming because somehow when I did the first rebase in the steps above that it messed with the commit hashes and has confused git. What steps should I take to do this correctly?

The goal here is to end up in the initial state (branches 1 commit ahead of each other) but with all the changes from mainbranch in all the branches

Comment: Seems it would work more cleanly if you just used `git rebase -r` instead of `-i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pull -r` rebases the new commits from your `mainbranch`, so they really get new hashes, and this makes git recognize them differently. I'm not sure how much text changes affect this behavior (I guess they do the most), but this (only?) can happen when rebasing commits that modify the same files. What you need is only to tell git to rebase the `branch1` and `branch2` branches with their *single* commits (I'm assuming this is clear from your question) because git does not track them itself.

```sh
git checkout mainbranch
git fetch -p
git pull --rebase

# rebase branch 1
git rebase --onto mainbranch branch1~1 branch1

# rebase branch 2
git rebase --onto branch1 branch2~1 branch2
```

Note that the rebase commands tell git to start rebasing according to these rules:

- `--onto <base>` tells git where to start building new commits onto (`--onto mainbranch` and then `--onto branch1`)
- `<upstream>~1` tells git the range/number of patches to be applied from (literally *one* only)
- `<downstream>` tells git the branch name to rebase

So, it's something like "git please rebase the branch `branch1` onto the current `mainbranch`, only one (`~1`) patch please", and then the same for the branch1-branch2 rebasing.

It might be easier to track down why it gets happening when using interactive rebase (at least you can see what causes that):

```sh
git checkout mainbranch
git fetch -p
git pull --rebase

# rebase branch 1
git checkout branch1
git rebase -i mainbranch
# note that the editor opens with more than one command: two or more picks (depends on the number of commits on main branch)
# simply remove all commands except the last `pick` command that picks the only commit from the branch1 branch

# rebase branch 2
git checkout branch2
git rebase -i branch1
# the same here: note that this will also include the original commit from branch1 that should be dropped too
# keep the last `pick` command only
```

Once it's done, in both scenarios (you decide which you prefer to follow), `git log --oneline` would produce something like:

```sh
CCCCCC (branch2) the only commit from branch2
BBBBBB (branch1) the only commit from branch1
AAAAAA (mainbranch) the tip commit at mainbranch
...
```

If you're familiar with what happens there and you feel safe with doing rebases and understand that something may go wrong, you can then even do something like:

```
git checkout mainbranch
git fetch -p
git pull --rebase

# rebase branch 1
git rebase master
git rebase --skip # assuming conflicts will occur here
                  # and this is equivalent to dropping the current patch from the interactive rebase (scenario 2 above)
                  # or excluding the commit from the commit range (scenario 1 above)
# possibly more `git rebase --skip` (unless the only patch is applied)

# rebase branch 2
git rebase branch1
git rebase --skip # one time than the previous rebase because of the old "branch1 commit on branch2" commit
```

I prefer the last one because I can see it right in my bash prompt (number of patches to apply, aheads/behinds after the rebase is completed, etc), but I always double check the result using `git log` before force-pushing.

Comment: i've tested the first approach and it worked perfectly thanks, the 2nd rebase was smooth :) i assume the ~1 means that the branch is 1 commit ahead of the other branch? i'll try the other approaches also and hopefully settle into one of them - many thanks for all your help :) PS loved the tip to check git log locally is as expected before force push

Comment: @danday74 _i assume the ~1 means that the branch is 1 commit ahead of the other branch_ No, it means the range of the commits to take patches from: you can inspect the range of the patches to be applied by using git log: `git log branch~1..branch` -- it will show you exactly one patch, and the only to be rebased onto another branch. So, basically, you just tell git _what to do_ (interactive rebase is it in visual form: it lets you _program_ what to do).

Comment: Note that rebasing is only a set of commands that instruct git to apply (or squash, or drop, etc) a series of patches onto another commit (not necessarily a branch). In your particular case you could even do all the same by using git reset and git cherry-pick. In general, rebasing is all about adding patches onto a base commit.

Comment: thanks for help :) i tried the 2nd approach today ... following your steps exactly, i only had one pick when i ran git rebase -i mainbranch (although i had 2 picks to choose from when running git rebase -i branch1) not sure why I only had 1 pick on first rebase - due to uncertainty I resorted to your 1st approach again - any thoughts? many thx

Comment: @danday74 I cannot tell, because I don't know the state of your branches on that moment, and whether you used `git checkout` to switch between branches (note that `git rebase` behaves somewhat differently for `<branch>`, `<branch> <branch>` and `--onto <branch> <branch> <branch>` scenarios). If you were on the branch1 branch when starting `git rebase -i mainbranch`, most likely you already had it rebased onto the mainbranch branch. And most likely you haven't had the branch2 branch rebased (therefore it might also incorporate the old commit from the branch1 branch, therefore different hash.)